# I cant solve the error: AttributeError: module 'torch._C' has no attribute '_cuda_setDevice' in python (anaconda)

Tags: pytorch

I´m trying to run a project I got on github: https://github.com/ranahanocka/MeshCNN

First of all, I created an environment in anaconda with .yml files that come in ranahanocka's project, then I got errors related to the CUDA installation.

To solve it, I followed this tutorial to install CUDA and I got rid of that error:

```
conda install -c anaconda cudatoolkit=10.1
```

But now I get these errors:

[image]

In `train.py`:

[image]

In `base_option.py`:

[image]

And in `__init__.py`:

[image]

I don't know how to fix it, I have read several forums but no solution has helped me. I have tried installing this:

```
pip install torch===1.9.0+cu111 torchvision===0.10.0+cu111 torchaudio===0.9.0 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu111/torch_stable.html
```

But in the middle of downloading I get these errors:

[image]

[image]

I don't know what can happen, besides, I don't understand very well how CUDA works and its dependencies, so I'm sorry if I don't provide the necessary information.

Comment: by the wat, the version of cuda that I have installed is 12.1

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that torch or cuda is not properly installed. In my case, someone has updated the Cuda version so I faced a similar issue.

In the command line you can check if you have Cuda available or not;

```
python

import torch

print(torch.cuda.is_available())
```

It should return **True** if not then you need to install Cuda or torch.

Check which Cuda version the GPU has:

```
nvidia-smi
```

I used this command to install the cuda and torch in my environment which solved my issue;

```
conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio pytorch-cuda=12.1 -c pytorch-nightly -c nvidia
```